# Maven filtering - custom patterns

Tags: java, maven, properties, filter

in many files (JAVA, XML, properties) I have custom patterns like

```
@datasource.jndiname
```

or

```
@jms.destination.name.
```

In my parent POM I have already defined the values for replacing these pattern but I have no idea how to do it. All the discussions here are talking about patterns like

```
${db.driverClass}.
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

this works by filtering resources like described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). But this is normaly only used for e.g. properties-files or similar, not source-files (*.java).

Answer (score 0):

Set of delimiters for expressions to filter within the resources. These delimiters are specified in the form beginToken*endToken. If no * is given, the delimiter is assumed to be the same for start and end.

So, the default filtering delimiters might be specified as:

```
<delimiters>
  <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
  <delimiter>@</delimiter>
</delimiters>
```

Since the @ delimiter is the same on both ends, we don't need to specify @*@ (though we can).

Please check the delimiters section here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html